# Convert a tuple to a string that is that tupple

Tags: python, string, tuples

At some point in my code, i have a list of tuples that i need to pass as a string, but a string that includes the structural elements of the tuple ie comas and parenthesis.

Currently i'm doing this :

```
   listofv = ''
   for tu in listof2tuple:
        ltu = '(' + tu[0] + ',' + tu[1] + ')'
        listofv.append(ltu)
   finalstring = ','.join(listofv)
```

While this works it seems strange, since printing the tuple in IDLE shows a string that is exactly what i want already.

What's the good way of doing this ?

Comment: What about calling `repr()` on it then? Also, why are you passing it as a string? It seems strange.

Comment: yes, repr() will do it ! the finalstring is used in a HTTP POST with a drastic syntax and i think it seems better to offload the construction of the argument list from the http call itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use repr:

```
>>> LoT
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
>>> repr(LoT)
'[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]'
```

Your code does not add the `[..]` braces for the list. If you do not want the list braces you can strip those off:

```
>>> repr(LoT).strip('[]')
'(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)'
```

Comment: Curious.  Why use `repr()` and not `str()`?

Comment: I cannot say better than [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/298607) great SO answer. `str()` would also work; `repr()` is less ambiguous of a result. *Usually* python simple data structures can be reconstituted (using ast.literal_eval) into their original form if `repr()` was used to create the string.

Comment: thanks, I'm familiar with the link you gave, and often there is no difference.